# Dynamically create map of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to be able to create a map of objects based on a data I am getting. The output should look something like that:

```
let var1 = 'source1'
let var2 = 'source2'
let data1=[data here]
let data2=[data here]
let table_specs ={
  var1: data1
  var2: data2
 }
```

I want to be able to assign var1 and var2 dynamically.

Comment: What is the input data your are getting? Doesn't the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method solve your problem?

Comment: We will need a lot more information. For starters, where is the data is coming from and have you tried anything?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica. I changed my post. I am getting data send from another part of the program.

Comment: Should `table_specs` be an [array](https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-time-complexity-for-beginners-arrays-hashmaps-linked-lists-stacks-queues-tutorial/#Array) (`[ data1, data2 ]`) or a [map](https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-time-complexity-for-beginners-arrays-hashmaps-linked-lists-stacks-queues-tutorial/#HashMaps) (`{ var1: data1, var2: data2 }`)?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already very close:

```js
let var1 = 'source1';
let var2 = 'source2';
let data1= {"foo": "bar" /* data here */};
let data2= {"baz": "bat" /* data here */};
let table_specs ={
  [var1]: data1,
  [var2]: data2,
}

console.log(table_specs);
```

The key part is the square brackets (`[]`) around the `var1` and `var2` properties. This is known as "[computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)" and uses the *values* of the variables as the properties names instead of treating `var1` and `var2` as *literal* property names.

The value of `table_specs` will be:

```json
{
  "source1": { "foo": "bar" },
  "source2": { "baz": "bat" }
}
```

Replacing the "foo", "bar", etc. data with your own.

**Alternatively**

If you can't use the computed property names for some reason, then you can still set the property names dynamically with [property accessors using bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```js
let var1 = 'source1';
let var2 = 'source2';
let data1= {"foo": "bar" /* data here */};
let data2= {"baz": "bat" /* data here */};
let table_specs ={};

table_specs[var1] = data1;
table_specs[var2] = data2;
```

This will produce the same result, though in a few more lines of code. The advantage is that you have more flexibility. You can use a loop, for example, if the number of "sources" is not known when you are writing the code, for example, whereas computed property names still require you to know the exact number of properties (which must remain consistent) even though you don't know the names.

For example, you could add a third source if a certain condition is met:

```js
if (some_condition) {
    table_specs[var3] = data3;
}
```

You would not be able to do this with computed property names.

Note that you can mix and match:

```js
let var1 = 'source1';
let var2 = 'source2';
let var3 = 'source3';
let data1= {"foo": "bar" /* data here */};
let data2= {"baz": "bat" /* data here */};
let data3= {"biz": "buz" /* data here */};
let table_specs ={
    [var1]: data1,
    [var2]: data2,
};

if (some_condition) {
    table_specs[var3] = data3;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much